# Conditional for negative integer

Tags: python, math, conditional-statements, bioinformatics

I'm defining a function that calculates the standard deviation of a list. Sometimes the mean of this list is negative and so my function can't take the square root of a negative, returning me with an error.

This seems simple, I just can't think of it. I want to write a conditional for my function saying that if there is a negative number, to multiply by -1 since the square root of a negative number cannot be taken.

How can I write this statement?

```
def stdevValue(lst):
"""calculates the standard deviation of a list of numbers
input: list of numbers
output: float that is the standard deviation
"""
    stdev = 0
    stdevCalc = (((sum(lst) - (meanValue(x)))/(len(lst)-1)))**0.5
    stdev += stdevCalc
    return stdev
```

Answer (score 16):

You appear to have misapplied the formula for standard deviation. You shouldn't need to handle the case of square root of negative numbers at all. You need to *square* each difference between the value and the mean before summing, like this:

```
def stdevValue(lst):
    m = meanValue(x) # wherever this comes from
    return (sum((x - m) ** 2 for x in lst) / len(lst)) ** 0.5
```

This ensures that the sum is *nonnegative*, so you can take the square root without being concerned about negative values. (If you want sample standard deviation, divide by `(len(lst) - 1)`).

See the Wikipedia article on [Standard Deviation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Standard_deviation) for more information and examples.

Comment: Note that for large data sets, this algorithm can suffer precision problems from roundoff errors.  See https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance for more numerically stable algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the context of the question, the answer is to use the built-in `abs`. But if you have a mathematical expression of type `y = sqrt(x)`, and `y` cannot be complex, then `x` cannot be negative. Any negative `x` denotes a problem, which could be rounding, wrapping, or, as in your case, an incorrect formula. Simply multiplying by -1, or taking the `abs`, will not fix the problem, it will give you the wrong answer. You should maybe consider how to deal with these cases (although I appreciate that for the case of standard deviation these errors are unlikely to arise).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to really get creative, you can square and square-root:

```
>>> import math
>>> x = -5
>>> math.sqrt((-5)**2)
5.0
```

Cheers